# as.integer(vector) changes the vector, even though it contains only round values (in r)

Tags: r

How come a when I transform a vector of 0s and 1s in r it deforms the vector and changes its values?

table(Prediction)

```
Prediction
  0   1 
318 133
```

as.integer(Prediction)

```
  [1] 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 2
[102] 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2
[203] 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2
[304] 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1
[405] 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 1
```

Comment: My guess is that the "Warning" section in `?factor` is relevant here. `x <- as.factor(0:1)`; `as.integer(x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose `Prediction` is a factor:

```
> Prediction <- factor(c(0, 0, 1, 1))
> table(Prediction)
Prediction
0 1 
2 2 
> as.integer(Prediction)
[1] 1 1 2 2
```

Maybe you want:

```
> as.integer(as.character(Prediction))
[1] 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: "The R-Inferno" FTW! Chapter 8.2.1